# help on css positioning problem. my toolbar can't sit on div below it

Tags: html, css

i have made a toolbar using links placed inside listitems but the problem is that i cant get my toolbar to sit on a "div" placed below it. This [is what i want to see](http://jsfiddle.net/syeAj/).

but this is what am getting in firefox[image: is what am getting in firefox]Notice the space between my 'toolbar' and the div below it. 
Questions

1. why is the code displaying properly in jsfiddle but displaying badly if i run it directly in fierfox?
2. How can i solve the problem?

ps:
here is the html

```
<html><head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head><body>
<div id='headercontainer'>
<h2>welcome to research club</h2>
    <ul class='mainNavigation'>
            <li><a class='currentPage' href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Meetups</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Feedback</a></li>

            <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='page'>
    <p> this is a simple paragraph inside the page that is full of meaningless words but tries to populate a page . mama miya tolina galya mamba eno.</p>
</div><!--#page-->
</html>
```

Here is the css

```
div#headercontainer
{
position:relative;
}
div#page
{
margin:0px 50px 0px 50px;
padding:0 450px 0 30px;
position:relative;
background:#181C21;
clear:right;
color:white;
}
ul.mainNavigation
{
list-style:none;
margin:0px 50px 0px 0px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0; right:0;
padding:0;
}
ul.mainNavigation li
{
background:#192839;
color:white;
float:left;
height:1.6em;
padding:5px;
}
ul.mainNavigation li a
{
color:#bbbbbb;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
height:1.6em;
font-size:0.9em;
}
ul.mainNavigation li a:hover
{
border-bottom:2px solid #0F67ff;
color:white;
}
ul.mainNavigation li a.currentPage
{
border-bottom:2px solid #176092;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you haven't added a general selector to put all margins and paddings to 0, in this case you would need to add:

```
div#headercontainer {
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

or

```
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
}
```

All browsers have some basic setups for non defined elements meaning I can set the I want all texts to be white instead of black and if you haven't set the color all the texts will be written in white.

Hoping this will help…

Answer (score 0):

Use float and clear instead of position absolute.
Like this:

```
div#headercontainer{
float:left;
    position:relative;
}
h2{
    float:left;
}
ul.mainNavigation{
    float:right;
}
#page{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}
```

Hope this help... (This is my first answer on this website :S)